# Gradle not building android project due to failing to create Jar file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Whenever i try to build an android project in android studio via gradle i get this error (i'm using gradle 8.5) :

```
Cause: invalid entry CRC (expected 0x473cfe14 but got 0xa0ec9cbb)
```

and

```
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\...\jars-9\1526456230b4b4f56779692f3bccef7d\app.jar.
> org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\...\.gradle\caches\jars-9\1526456230b4b4f56779692f3bccef7d\app.jar.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\...\.gradle\caches\jars-9\1526456230b4b4f56779692f3bccef7d\app.jar.
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.unchecked(UncheckedException.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer$ParallelTransformExecutor.lambda$transformAll$5(DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.java:332)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheCoordinator.useCache(DefaultCacheCoordinator.java:248)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:189)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:224)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer$ParallelTransformExecutor.transformAll(DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.java:308)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.transformFiles(DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.java:198)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.lambda$instrumentingPipeline$1(DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.lambda$agentInstrumentingPipeline$2(DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.java:155)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.transform(DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptClassPathResolver.resolveClassPath(DefaultScriptClassPathResolver.java:71)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultBuildLogicBuilder.lambda$resolveClassPath$0(DefaultBuildLogicBuilder.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultBuildLogicBuildQueue.build(DefaultBuildLogicBuildQueue.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultBuildLogicBuilder.resolveClassPath(DefaultBuildLogicBuilder.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.getInstrumentedScriptClassPath(DefaultScriptHandler.java:102)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.defineScriptHandlerClassScope(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:211)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:93)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:119)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.code.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:43)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultInitScriptProcessor.process(DefaultInitScriptProcessor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.initialization.InitScriptHandler$1.run(InitScriptHandler.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.initialization.InitScriptHandler.executeScripts(InitScriptHandler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.initialization.InitScriptHandlingSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(InitScriptHandlingSettingsLoader.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.CacheConfigurationsHandlingSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CacheConfigurationsHandlingSettingsLoader.java:36)
    at org.gradle.initialization.GradlePropertiesHandlingSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(GradlePropertiesHandlingSettingsLoader.java:38)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(DefaultSettingsPreparer.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer$LoadBuild.doLoadBuild(BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer.java:71)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer$LoadBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$prepareSettings$1(VintageBuildModelController.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$14(StateTransitionController.java:255)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:254)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transitionIfNotPreviously$11(StateTransitionController.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transitionIfNotPreviously(StateTransitionController.java:209)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareSettings(VintageBuildModelController.java:80)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.getLoadedSettings(VintageBuildModelController.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$notInState$3(StateTransitionController.java:132)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.notInState(StateTransitionController.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.loadSettings(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:118)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.AbstractBuildState.ensureProjectsLoaded(AbstractBuildState.java:115)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.GradleBuildBuilder.create(GradleBuildBuilder.java:58)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.GradleBuildBuilder.create(GradleBuildBuilder.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildScopedBuilder.build(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:206)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingBuilder$1.call(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:337)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingBuilder.build(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:334)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildToolingModelController$AbstractToolingScope.getModel(DefaultBuildToolingModelController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:106)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:113)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:76)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getBuildModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getBuildModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:131)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.beforeTasks(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.beforeTasks(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$fromBuildModel$2(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:119)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$7(StateTransitionController.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:116)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:81)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:140)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:123)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.execute(InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitProblems.execute(InitProblems.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:128)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\...\.gradle\caches\jars-9\1526456230b4b4f56779692f3bccef7d\app.jar.
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.unchecked(UncheckedException.java:74)
    ... 177 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\...\.gradle\caches\jars-9\1526456230b4b4f56779692f3bccef7d\app.jar.
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathBuilder.jar(ClasspathBuilder.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.transforms.BaseClasspathElementTransform.transform(BaseClasspathElementTransform.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.transform(InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.java:136)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.transform(InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.java:103)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.transformFile(DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.java:270)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.lambda$cachedFile$10(DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.java:263)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.unchecked(UncheckedException.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer$ParallelTransformExecutor.lambda$transformAll$1(DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.java:321)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to process the entry 'org/apache/commons/imaging/common/mylzw/MyLzwCompressor$ByteArray.class' from 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio 2022.1.1.19\lib\app.jar'
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.transforms.BaseClasspathElementTransform.visitEntry(BaseClasspathElementTransform.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.transforms.BaseClasspathElementTransform.lambda$visitEntries$1(BaseClasspathElementTransform.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathWalker.visitJarContents(ClasspathWalker.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathWalker.visit(ClasspathWalker.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.transforms.BaseClasspathElementTransform.visitEntries(BaseClasspathElementTransform.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.transforms.BaseClasspathElementTransform.lambda$transform$0(BaseClasspathElementTransform.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathBuilder.buildJar(ClasspathBuilder.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathBuilder.jar(ClasspathBuilder.java:55)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry CRC (expected 0x473cfe14 but got 0xa0ec9cbb)
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.read(ByteStreams.java:932)
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.readFully(ByteStreams.java:800)
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.readFully(ByteStreams.java:784)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.archive.impl.AbstractZipEntry$1.apply(AbstractZipEntry.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.archive.impl.AbstractZipEntry$1.apply(AbstractZipEntry.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.archive.impl.StreamZipInput$StreamZipEntry.withInputStream(StreamZipInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.archive.impl.AbstractZipEntry.getContent(AbstractZipEntry.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathWalker$ZipClasspathEntry.getContent(ClasspathWalker.java:115)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.transforms.BaseClasspathElementTransform.processClassFile(BaseClasspathElementTransform.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.transforms.ClasspathElementTransformForAgent.processClassFile(ClasspathElementTransformForAgent.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.transforms.BaseClasspathElementTransform.visitEntry(BaseClasspathElementTransform.java:86)
    ... 16 more
```